# Nodejs, Express + Swagger

Tags: node.js, express.js, swagger

Olá, pessoal eu fui incumbido de uma missão de implementar o swagger em uma aplicação express, com finalidade de gerar o swagger.json para o deploy do apigateway da AWS.

Já tentei utilizar o swaggerJSDoc, swagger-ui-node... entre outros.

O mais próximo que eu cheguei do meu objetivo com o swaggerJSDoc, só que para ele funcionar eu precisar adicionar vários annotations nas rotas, como esse:

```
  /**
 * @swagger
 * /add:
 *   post:
 *     summary: Add more animal
 *     description: Add animals to the list
 *     tags:
 *       - animals
  *     requestBody:
 *       content:
 *         application/json:
 *           schema:
 *             type: object
 *             properties:
 *               animals:
 *                 type: array
 *                 items:
 *                   type: string
 *     responses:
 *       200:
 *         description: Adds the animals in body
 *         schema:
 *           type: object
 *           properties:
 *             message:
 *               type: string
 *               default: 'Added'
 */
     app.post('/add', (req, res) => {
      // ...
     });
```

Existe alguma forma de gerar esses annotations de forma automática, para não precisar fazer tudo na unha? Ou alguma outra forma de criar esse swagger.json a partir das routes, sem precisar escrever esses annotations?

```
{
"swagger": "2.0",
"info": {
    "version": "2018-09-25T20:57:59Z",
    "title": "swagger.json"
},
"host": "localhost",
"basePath": "/",
"schemes": [
    "https"
],
"paths": { }
}
```

Comment: Existe uma extensão para o vscode cujo nome não me lembro agora. Mas que existe, existe, eu já usei.

Comment: Codewind OpenAPI Tools ?

Answer (score 0):

Sim, a lib [swagger-autogen](https://www.npmjs.com/package/swagger-autogen) realiza a construção automática da documentação do Swagger.

Primeiro, instale o pacote com: `npm i swagger-autogen`

Crie um arquivo chamado `swagger.js`, por exemplo, na raiz do projeto e insira o seguinte conteúdo:

**swagger.js**

```js
const swaggerAutogen = require('swagger-autogen')()

swaggerAutogen('./swagger-output.json', ['./routes.js']);
```

Onde:

'./swagger-output.json': será o nome do arquivo gerado com as specificações do Swagger.

['./routes.js']: É o arquivo onde inciam suas rotas, ou os arquivos contendo os endpoints.

Por ultimo, no arquivo package.json, adicione um script para gerar a documentação:

```js
"scripts": {
    "swagger-autogen": "node ./swagger.js"
}
```

Basta executar: `npm run swagger-autogen`

E a documentação será gerada e gravada no arquivo swagger-output.json.

Para adicionar descrições, tags, sumário, etc, veja em: https://www.npmjs.com/package/swagger-autogen#endpoints

A lib tem suporte a Swagger 2.0 e OpenAPI v3.

Link com alguns projetos de exemplos:

[Exemplo usando Rotas](https://github.com/davibaltar/example-swagger-autogen-with-router)

[Exemplo sem usar Rotas](https://github.com/davibaltar/example-swagger-autogen)